# Where to find the script files for the Documents(of the Collections) in MongoDB/data/db after inserting them using MongoDB shell?

Tags: json, mongodb

Our professor told us to upload a script file(.json) for the assignment but to create a database. We are using MongoDB and I can't find the .json files in which the Documents(tuples) are stored for the Collections(relations). I want a .json file where all the Database files i.e. Collections and Documents are stored. Or if I could just export the Documents I have just created in the shell to another file(.json).

Comment: Are you looking for something like `mongoexport`?

Comment: Yes, because it creates a json file.